# Passing the same argument to multiple nested function

Tags: r, function, arguments, nested-function

I would like to pass the same argument to several nested functions. For example, given 2 functions:

```
 fun1 = function(x){x^2}
 fun2 = function(x,FUN,...) { x + FUN(...) }
```

I would like to implement something like this:

```
 fun2(x=10,FUN=fun1)  ## this returns error
```

In this example, I would like to get an output of *10 + 10^2 = 110*

I have seen this answered question: [Passing arbitrary arguments to multiple nested functions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330220/passing-arbitrary-arguments-to-multiple-nested-functions-in-r) but I specifically wish to pass the **same** argument to multiple nested functions.

Comment: just to be sure, why not a factory function instead? (see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `...` is what follows the `FUN` argument, i.e. nothing. You could play with `sys.call` to reuse the arguments, e.g.:

```
 fun2 <- function(FUN, x, ...) {
     cl <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE) # unevaluated expression `fun2(x=10,FUN=fun1)`
# Note: sys.call would work only if the arguments were named
     cl[[1]] <- cl$FUN # substitute `fun2`. Now cl is `fun1(x=10,FUN=fun1)`
     cl$FUN <- NULL # remove FUN argument. Now cl is `fun1(x=10)`
     result.of.FUN <- eval.parent(cl) # evaluate the modified expression
     x + result.of.FUN
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `x`s are not the same in both functions.

Consider this:

```
fun1 <- function(y) y^2 
fun2 <- function(x,FUN) x + FUN(x) 

> fun2(x=10, FUN=fun1)
[1] 110
```

You see, if you don't pass the argument with `FUN(x)`, `fun1()` doesn't recognize the `x=10`.

Comment: I like what you're doing here but have 2 comments. (i) defining fun1 in terms of x (i.e. fun1 <- function(x) {x^2}) will return the correct result and (ii) I am looking for a more general answer.  The way you define fun2 indicates that the input function (FUN) will always depend on x, which isn't necessarily true.  It would be nice to have a solution where the input function (FUN) doesn't need to have its inputs defined explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Another somewhat less robust but perhaps simpler solution as compared Kamil's, is to rely on the argument order of the defined functions as such:

```
fun1 = function(x){x^2}
fun2 = function(x,FUN,...) { x + FUN(...) }
```

Then running fun2 as:

```
 > fun2(x=10,FUN=fun1,10)
 [1] 110
```

This again relies on knowing the order of the function arguments, which is somewhat dangerous.